# MS Excel VBA - Inserting a cell's value within text input message to user

Tags: vba, excel

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to insert a cell's value within a text input message to the user. The value in this cell is a host country's currency that I would like to appear in the input box, always located in cell B6. I am not well versed in Excel VBA but knowing the capabilities in Access I'm sure its a matter of proper naming convention. Thank you greatly for you time!

Current Code:

```
mlt = InputBox("Enter Host Currency(B6)/USD FX Rate:")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub inputbox()
    Dim mlt As String 
    Dim myString As String
    myString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6).Value
    mlt = Application.Inputbox("Enter Host Currency " & myString & "/USD FX Rate:")
End Sub
```

`.Cells(2,6)` is referring to the cell of the second column (B) and the sixth row.

Alternatively you could use:
`myString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value`

Comment: PS- if you're going to use the user entry as a number for calculations you should Dim mlt As Long, but you would need to set an error handler to force them to enter a number.

Comment: Got it to work, thank you greatly! Just copied the myString line and the mlt line within my current procedure, along with the Dim myString! Thanks again.